# Why is it necessary to GROUP BY/aggregate all SELECT expressions if you only want to aggregate one of them?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**My Experience Level: Beginner** (started learning a few weeks ago, have yet to use professionally/for a project)

So this nice, simple query works. No GROUP BY, only the aggregation function AVG. Nothing else is selected.

```
SELECT
  AVG(num_bikes_available)
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`
```

This gives

| f0_ |
| --- |
| 13.249537892791142 |

However, if I add another expression to the SELECT clause, such as `station_id`

```
SELECT
  station_id,
  AVG(num_bikes_available)
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`
```

I get the error `SELECT list expression references column station_id which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:3]`

What I'm expecting to happen is to be returned a list of station IDs, each with the average num_bikes_available for the entire dataset next to it, like such:

| station_id | f0_ |
| --- | --- |
| 1bb1af93-b433-4da7-8054-009c85f7755a | 13.249537892791142 |
| c638ec67-9ac0-416f-944f-619926144931 | 13.249537892791142 |
| 66de0cab-0aca-11e7-82f6-3863bb44ef7c | 13.249537892791142 |

I know that to get this result, I need to use the subquery:

```
SELECT
  station_id,
  (SELECT
    AVG(num_bikes_available)
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`)
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`
```

But I'm curious as to why.

I know that to resolve the error, I need to use `GROUP BY station_id`

```
SELECT
  station_id,
  AVG(num_bikes_available)
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`
GROUP BY
  station_id
```

But again, why? Ignoring that the result isn't what I want, I'm lost as to *why* the GROUP BY clause is necessary?

My guess would have to be that because `station_id` and `AVG(num_of_bikes_available)` have unequal row numbers the interpreter might be getting confused. But then what about adding it in a subquery unconfuses it?

Comment: The GROUP BY main purpose is to aggregate per group. List all stations, and for each station count its number of bikes etc.

Comment: You are simply asking the DB to calculate averages for each `station_id`  separately.  Without `GROUP BY` your aggregation will apply to all rows.

Comment: The parser won't ***infer*** or ***guess*** your intentions. The syntax needs to cover all situations, from your trivial example to much more complex examples. In those complex situations the `GROUP BY` becomes necessary, and so it's ***always*** necessary when aggregating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL doesn't know in advance that you wanted to repeat the overall average on each row. Instead, when you introduced the "aggregate function" (`AVG`) to the query the default behaviour of SQL is to assume that what you want is the average **PER ROW**. Then SQL syntax rules require that you specify which columns are needed to form those rows (i.e. how to aggregate the data) and this is done via the `GROUP BY` clause.

Because your expectation is different to that default behaviour you do need to take an additional step to produce your wanted result, which you have done by introducing the subquery within the select clause.

Perhaps the following will help demonstrate. Here the data contains more than one row per "code" and so you can get aggregated values "per row" using the group by clause. However if you want the overall calculation instead, or as well, you need an extra calculation.

```
CREATE TABLE mydata (
  code VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  value DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  asof DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO mydata (code, value, asof) VALUES 
('1bb1af93-b433-4da7-8054-009c85f7755a', 11.5, '2023-09-01'),
('c638ec67-9ac0-416f-944f-619926144931', 12.25, '2023-08-02'),
('66de0cab-0aca-11e7-82f6-3863bb44ef7c', 13.3, '2024-10-01'),
('1bb1af93-b433-4da7-8054-009c85f7755a', 14.2, '2025-06-02'),
('c638ec67-9ac0-416f-944f-619926144931', 15, '2025-11-01');



SELECT
      code
    , avg(value) AS av_per_code
    , (select avg(value) from mydata) as av_overall
    , min(asof) as min_asof_per_code
    , max(asof) as max_asof_per_code
    , (select min(asof) from mydata) as min_asof__overall
    , (select  max(asof) from mydata) as max_asof_overall  
FROM mydata
GROUP BY
      code
```

| code | av_per_code | av_overall | min_asof_per_code | max_asof_per_code | min_asof__overall | max_asof_overall |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1bb1af93-b433-4da7-8054-009c85f7755a | 12.850 | 13.250 | 2023-09-01 | 2025-06-02 | 2023-08-02 | 2025-11-01 |
| c638ec67-9ac0-416f-944f-619926144931 | 13.625 | 13.250 | 2023-08-02 | 2025-11-01 | 2023-08-02 | 2025-11-01 |
| 66de0cab-0aca-11e7-82f6-3863bb44ef7c | 13.300 | 13.250 | 2024-10-01 | 2024-10-01 | 2023-08-02 | 2025-11-01 |

See this working example at [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rOtgoc7o).

Answer (score 0):

When you run:

```
SELECT
  AVG(num_bikes_available)
FROM 
  bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`
```

The interpreter will calculate the average for the whole dataset, because there are no other columns introduced in the SELECT clause.

But when you run:

```
SELECT
  station_id,
  AVG(num_bikes_available)
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`
```

The database doesn't know how to aggregate the results. Should it calculate the average for the entire dataset? or for each station_id? In other words, when we don't specify the GROUP BY clause, it leads to ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

DB engines cannot list a column together with an aggregate as long as its not a part of group by clause. For your expected result, you may want to consider querying using window function rather than using group by clause.

***SELECT
station_id,
AVG(num_bikes_available) over() as avg
FROM
bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations***

If you wanted to find avg based on 'station_id' just like group by clause you can add **partition by station_id** inside over().

***SELECT
station_id,
AVG(num_bikes_available) over(partition by station_id) as avg
FROM
bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations***